# Применение Environment к загружаемым настройкам в python

Tags: python, json, settings

Хочу использовать следующий синтаксис для подстановки переменных окружения в настройки, как {env[key]}

```
>>> person = {'first':'Reuven', 'last':'Lerner'}
>>> "Your name is {p[first]}.".format(p=person)
```

настройки вычитываю из текстового файла, в котором сохранён JSON

```
if (self.settings is None) and os.path.exists(self.settings_file):
    with open(self.settings_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        file_content_env = file_content.format(env=environment)
        self.settings = json.loads(file_content_env)
```

но оно валится с ошибкой.

```
file_content_env = file_content.format(env=environment)
KeyError: '\n        "Type"'
```

Как правильно прогружать настройки? Или может кто потыкает в решение лучше?

Добавил пример который крэшит

```
environment = {
    "date": time.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
    "datetime": time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M"),
    "workdir": os.path.dirname("")
}

file_content = """[
    {
        "Type": "test",
        "Name": "Task from {env[datetime]}",
        "Path": "{env[workdir]}\\test"
    }
]"""

file_content_env = file_content.format(env=environment)
```

Comment: Вместо создания json текста с помощью форматирования, лучше манипулируйте данные как обычный словарь (загрузите json предварительно, если нужно)  и запишите нужные данные прямо по ключу в словарь,  а конце в json можно назад преобразовать, если необходимо. Пример: `settings = json.load(f); settings["Path"] = ...`

Comment: Не уловил, чем лучше и как это должно выглядеть в моём случае.
json служит в качестве файла с настройками. Предполагается что конфиг весь в однмо месте, без залезания в код, но гибкости plain text не хватает, поэтому для некоторых типовых вещей (метка времени, некоторые служебные пути) предполагается ввести переменные по аналогии с переменными окружения в обычных shell скриптах. На выходе JSON не нужен, он нужен на входе, чтобы его можно было удобно в любом нормальном редакторе править с хайлайтингом и валидировать сразу. Дальше уже параметры полученные из json используются нужными модулями.

Comment: Не хотелось размазывать по коду руками сотню replace после вычитки конфига, когда казалось бы есть список с "переменными окружения" и есть конфиг который можно обработать как plain_text.

Comment: Если json только на входе, то ещё проще: шаг #1: загрузить json: `settings = json.load(f)` Шаг #2 внести изменения из environment: `settings["Path"] = environment["workdir"] / "test"` (используется pathlib для удобства). Всё.

Comment: environment["workdir"] / "test" - является хардкодом, сюда уже пользователь не влезет и не изменит как ему надо. Опять же каждый параметр вот так руками придётся за уши притягивать (а параметров может быть очень много)

Comment: Если у вас содержимое шаблона пользователем определяется—это вы такой свой язык конфигурации придумываете: помесь json и Python format шаблона, то попробуйте сперва существующий язык использовать, который поддерживает нужную функциональность (к примеру, достаточно ли configparser? или вообще Python в качестве языка конфигурации использовать?)

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема из-за фигурных скобок. Чтобы `format` игнорировал фигурные скобки необходимо их повторить два раза: `{{` и `}}`

```
import os
import time
import json
import datetime

environment = {
    "date": time.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
    "datetime": time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M"),
    "workdir": os.path.dirname("")
}

file_content = """[
    {{
        "Type": "test",
        "Name": "Task from {datetime}",
        "Path": "{workdir}\\test"
    }}
]"""

file_content_env = file_content.format(**environment)

print(file_content_env)
```

Если вам нужен валидный `json` и при этом нужна подстановки в строки, придется делать это в цикле:

```
import os
import time
import json

environment = {
    "date": time.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
    "datetime": time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M"),
    "workdir": os.path.dirname("")
}

file_content = """[
    {
        "Type": "test",
        "Name": "Task from {datetime}",
        "Path": "{workdir}\\test"
    }
]"""


js = json.loads(file_content)

for key in js[0]:
    js[0][key] = js[0][key].format(**environment)

print(js)
```

Comment: Я что-то такое и хотел, но он крэшит при обработке многострочного контента

Comment: Сложно сказать, вы не привели пример того, что передаете. Причин для краша может быть много, одной из причин может быть то что вы не словарь передаете в format.

Comment: Добавил в конец основного поста пример

Comment: У вас проблема из-за фигурных скобок. `format` находит первые фигурные скобки, и пытается туда подставить значение. Но в первых скобках находится неверное поле для подставления.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: В итоге на входе не валидный JSON. Жаль

Comment: Вариант с тупым перебором по словарю имеет одну большую проблему - он не обойдёт вложенные структуры, а они есть в моём случае

Comment: Обойдите вложенные структуры рекурсивно.